# parsing media content from yahoo rss feed xcode 4.5 ios

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, xcode4.5

I'm trying to obtain the url contained in media:content tag of the Yahoo RSS feed. The code for didStartElement(), foundCharacters() and didEndElement() is given below:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kChannelElementName]) {
        Channel = [[channel alloc] init];
        dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [Channel setItemCollectionArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];


        return ;
}

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kItemElementName]) {
       itemCollection=[[ItemDataCollection alloc] init];


        return ;
     }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kTitleElementName]) {


        return ;

    }
  if([elementName isEqualToString:kItemDescription]){
        return ;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kItemImage]) {
        NSString *urlString = attributeDict[@"url"];
        if(urlString){
            [dict setObject:urlString forKey:@"img"];
        }

        return ;
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if (currentElementData == nil) {
        self.currentElementData = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    [currentElementData appendString:string];     
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kChannelElementName]) {
        [channelCollection addObject:Channel];

        NSLog(@"channel are***********%@",channelCollection);
        for(ItemDataCollection *mydata in Channel.itemCollectionArray){
            NSLog(@"___%@ <><><><><> desc \n  %@ <><><><><><> img \n %@",mydata.title,mydata.itemDescription,mydata.titleImage);

        }


        Channel =nil;

    }

   else  if ([elementName isEqualToString:kItemElementName]) {
       [[Channel itemCollectionArray] addObject:itemCollection];
       itemCollection=nil;

        }
   else  if ([elementName isEqualToString:kTitleElementName]) {
       if(itemCollection==nil){

       Channel.title=currentElementData;
       }
       else{

           itemCollection.title=currentElementData;

       }



   }
   else  if ([elementName isEqualToString:kPubDate]) {
       Channel.pubDate=currentElementData;


   }
  else  if ([elementName isEqualToString: kItemDescription]) {
      if(itemCollection!=nil){
       itemCollection.itemDescription=currentElementData;


   } 
  }
     else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:content"]){
          if(itemCollection!=nil){
              itemCollection.titleImage = currentElementData;
          }
      } 
   // [currentElementData release];


    self.currentElementData = nil;
}
```

I'm printing the parsed data as log. The image is showing as null. Everything else eg;title and description is getting obtained properly. How can I fix it? Probably something needs to be done in the didEndElement method. But I don't know what. I've been racking my brains over this since yesterday. Please help!!

I made some changes in didStartElement():

```
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:kItemImage]) {
            NSString *urlString = attributeDict[@"url"];
            if(urlString){
                [dict setObject:urlString forKey:@"img"];
                NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
                mString = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlString];
```

and some change in didEndElement():

```
else if([currentElementData rangeOfString:@"media:content"].location){
          if(itemCollection!=nil){
            //  [currentElementData appendString:dict];
              itemCollection.titleImage = mString;
          }
      }
```

mString has been declared as a mutable string. Images are getting parsed now. Their urls are getting displayed in the log. The problem is that now, the last image is repeated twice.. It is probably because the last feed does not have an image, so it is using the previous one. How to fix that? I mean, there can be multiple feeds without images. in that case, it should actually display null rather than the url of the previous image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don`t know well about Yahoo rss feed but i hope it will help you.....

Just tryout this....

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {          

  currentElement = [elementName copy];
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentImage = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 }
 else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:content"]) {
         currentImage = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"img src"];
         NSLog(@"Url:%@", currentImage); 
    }
 }
}
```